# Rendering container fails to start: system cannot find the file specified

Tags: jss, docker, nextjs

I am adding a `rendering` service/container to my solution. I see this error from the `rendering` container when running `docker compose up`:

```
Error response from daemon: container 223aedd168af9ccc07e46bf918d04ecabdf43baecfc3706b534574786dd1b54f encountered an error during hcs::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF642B5A1DB: (caller: 00007FF642B0E19A) Exception(3) tid(398) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
rendering:
  build:
    args:
      PARENT_IMAGE: mysite-nodejs:${VERSION:-latest}
    context: ./docker/build/rendering
    target: debug
  depends_on:
    cd:
      condition: service_started
    nodejs:
      condition: service_started
  environment:
    JSS_EDITING_SECRET: some.secret
    NEXTJS_DIST_DIR: .next-container
    PUBLIC_URL: https://rendering.mysite.localhost
    SITECORE_API_HOST: http://cd
  image: mysite-rendering:${VERSION:-latest}
  labels:
    - "traefik.enable=true"
    - "traefik.http.routers.rendering-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
    - "traefik.http.routers.rendering-secure.rule=Host(`rendering.mysite.localhost`)"
    - "traefik.http.routers.rendering-secure.tls=true"
    - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors-headers.headers.accesscontrolalloworigin=*"
    - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors-headers.headers.accesscontrolallowmethods=GET,OPTIONS,PUT"
    - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors-headers.headers.accesscontrolallowheaders=Authorization,Content-Type,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Range,Range"
    - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors-headers.headers.accesscontrolallowcredentials=true"
    - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors-headers.headers.addvaryheader=true"
    - "traefik.http.routers.cm-secure.middlewares=cors-headers"
  volumes:
  - C:\path\to\nextjs\project:C:\app

nodejs:
  build:
    args:
      NODEJS_VERSION: 18.12.1
      PARENT_IMAGE: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
    context: ./docker/build/nodejs
  image: mysite-nodejs:${VERSION:-latest}
  scale: 0
```

**rendering Dockerfile:**

```
# escape=`

#
# Development-only image for running Next.js in a containerized environment.
# Assumes that the Next.js rendering host source is mounted to c:\app.
#

ARG PARENT_IMAGE
FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE} as debug

# TODO: set in env and init
#WORKDIR /projects/NPCorpWeb
WORKDIR c:\\app

EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["start.cmd"]
```

**nodejs Dockerfile:**

```
# escape=`

#
# Basic Windows node.js image for use as a parent image in the solution.
#

ARG PARENT_IMAGE
FROM $PARENT_IMAGE

ARG NODEJS_VERSION

WORKDIR c:\build
RUN curl.exe -sS -L -o node.zip https://nodejs.org/dist/v%NODEJS_VERSION%/node-v%NODEJS_VERSION%-win-x64.zip"
RUN tar.exe -xf node.zip -C C:\
RUN move C:\node-v%NODEJS_VERSION%-win-x64 c:\node
RUN del node.zip

USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN SETX /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\node"
USER ContainerUser

# In order for nextjs 12+ to work, we need to ensure that
# Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable is installed.
# More info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc
USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN curl -fSLo vc_redist.x64.exe https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe `
  && start /w vc_redist.x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart `
  && del vc_redist.x64.exe
USER ContainerUser
```

I never see anything show up in the Docker logs about `rendering` but for `nodejs` I see only this:

```
2023-10-26 14:55:31 mysite-nodejs-1      | Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.4974]
2023-10-26 14:55:31 mysite-nodejs-1      | (c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2023-10-26 14:55:31 mysite-nodejs-1      | 
2023-10-26 14:55:31 mysite-nodejs-1      | C:\build>
```

So far I have tried:

- Restarting my PC
- `docker compose build --no-cache`
- Disabling the `Dockerfile` for `rendering`
- Changing the entry point in the Dockerfile to `ENTRYPOINT "npm run start:connected"`

This question is similar to another question which appears to have been abandoned:
[xm-cloud-introduction_mvp-rendering_1 Cannot start service mvp-rendering: The system cannot find the file specified](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/33677/xm-cloud-introduction-mvp-rendering-1-cannot-start-service-mvp-rendering-the-sy)